# Why is my simulation getting a blank black screen having to do with anchors/constraints programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

Here is my code. The I'm trying to make the top of the webView anchor constrained to the bottom of the view controller's top layout guide, but I'm just getting a black screen and sometimes the **error in the console:**

```
 Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x608000284d30 _UILayoutSpacer:0x6080001aa560'UIVC-topLayoutGuide'.height == 20   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x6080002850a0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutSpacer:0x6080001aa560'UIVC-topLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fcfcac26cd0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000280fa0 h=--& v=--& WKWebView:0x7fcfcb09a400.midY == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000280ff0 h=--& v=--& WKWebView:0x7fcfcb09a400.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002846f0 V:[_UILayoutSpacer:0x6080001aa560'UIVC-topLayoutGuide']-(3)-[WKWebView:0x7fcfcb09a400]   (active)>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000281220 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' UIView:0x7fcfcac26cd0.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7fcfcac08120 )>"
)
```

**Code -**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class webViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    override func loadView() {
        self.view = UIView()
        let webView = WKWebView()
//        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        let topConstraint = webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 3)
        topConstraint.isActive = true

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        if let selectedURL = url {
            let request = NSURLRequest(url: selectedURL as URL) as URLRequest
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing which constraint was broken automatically - and if this doesn't fix things, add that please - I'm noticing several NSAutoResizingMaskLayoutConstraint issues. You need to set that mask to **false** for each view.

Comment: I'm sorry Rohan...add what? The commented out line?

Comment: Yep. I didn't see you commented that out. Again, if that doesn't work, add more to **both** the constraint dump (what did it do?) and what other constraints you've set.

Comment: That is the only constraint I've set inside this controller, and I still get a blank black screen when the window loads the view.

Comment: Hopefully we won't be asked to go to chat. Please give us **all** of the constraint problem - it should always tell what constraint it will break - along with **all* constraints - both in code and IB, along with any superview constraints. It really is impossible to debug constraint issues without that. (Unless, someone forgot/commented out turning off the auto resizing mask).

Comment: Yeah I think someone edited my original post and messed it up. No worries we can forget about it thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Add the navigation delegate:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Then listen to the error and navigation delegates, you will be able to see what really is or not going on.